# R: sequential ranking (1,1,1,2,2,2,etc) based on date of entry for each patient?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a column that ranks each person based on their date of entry, but since everyone's date of entry is unique, it's been challenging.

here's a reprex:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  unique_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
  date_of_entry = c("3-12-2001", "3-13-2001", "3-14-2001", "4-1-2001", "4-2-2001", "3-28-2001", "3-29-2001", "3-30-2001"))
```

What I want:

```r
df_desired <- data.frame(
  unique_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
  date_of_entry = c("3-12-2001", "3-13-2001", "3-14-2001", "4-1-2001", "4-2-2001", "3-28-2001", "3-29-2001", "3-30-2001"), 
  day_at_facility = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3))
```

basically, i want to order the days at facility, but I need it to restart based on each unique ID. let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: You can use `df$day_at_facility <- with(df, ave(seq_along(unique_id), unique_id, FUN = seq_along))`

Comment: You can take it @akrun, mine adds some but it's close enough to your comment I'd rather not step on toes here.

Comment: @r2evans It is a common dupe.  I don't want to get downvotes for answering :=)

Answer (score 0):

(This is a dupe of something, haven't found it yet, but in the interim ...)

### base R

```r
ave(rep(1L,nrow(df)), df$unique_id, FUN = seq_along)
# [1] 1 2 3 1 2 1 2 3
```

so therefore

```r
df$day_at_facility <- ave(rep(1L,nrow(df)), df$unique_id, FUN = seq_along)
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(unique_id) %>%
  mutate(day_at_facility = row_number())
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# # Groups:   unique_id [3]
#   unique_id date_of_entry day_at_facility
#       <dbl> <chr>                   <int>
# 1         1 3-12-2001                   1
# 2         1 3-13-2001                   2
# 3         1 3-14-2001                   3
# 4         2 4-1-2001                    1
# 5         2 4-2-2001                    2
# 6         3 3-28-2001                   1
# 7         3 3-29-2001                   2
# 8         3 3-30-2001                   3
```